# connecting sparksql in jupyter notebook to tableau/powerbi

Tags: pyspark, powerbi, tableau-api

I have performed some queries using pyspark on jupyter notebook now i want the outputs to be visualized in powerbi/tableau.
How do i do it ? I'm completely new to pyspark and need help !

Comment: Tableau connects to files or databases. So pick something to write your output to and connect to that.

Comment: I have created parquet files and stored it as csv now i need to connect it to tableau !